# Removing all occurrences of an int and returning new array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to find all occurrences of an element in an array and returning a new array with the occurrences removed and the array being adjusted for any differences in size. For example I want to remove all occurrences of 4 from the array {1,2,3,4,4,4} and return just {1,2,3}.

This is the code i've written

```
public static int[] removeElement(int[] array, int element) {

    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    for (int i =0;i<array.length;i++){
        if (array[i]==element){
            j++;
        }
    }
    int[] newArray = new int[array.length-j];

    for (int i =0;i<array.length-j;i++){
        if(array[i]!=element){
            newArray[k]=array[i];
            k++;
        }
    }
    return newArray;

}
```

However I get a very weird output

```
[I@3a0b2771
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're directly printing an array to the screen elsewhere in your code. Print each element in a for loop, and you'll iterate over the entire new array to see the changes.

```
for(int i=0;i<newArray.length;i++) { 
    System.out.println(newArray[i]);
}
```

Using the `[i]` notation on an array will access the element held at this index, in this case the i'th integer.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is the array *identity* rather than its contents. This is the default output when you try to print something that doesn't override the `toString()` method. From the documentation:

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:

```
 getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

In your case `[I` means that it is an int array.

There are a couple of ways you can print the array elements as you intend:

- Use `Arrays.toString()`: Use this when printing a simple array. In your case it would be something like:

  `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));`
- Use `Arrays.deepToString()`: You should use this when printing an array of arrays.

If you need to work with arrays, you should check the [Arrays class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html). It contains many methods for manipulating arrays that may be helpful.